# Latex \path command inside \newcommand definition not working?

Tags: latex, renewcommand

I would like to use the `\path` command inside a `\newcommand` definition inside a latex document. However my definition does not work as I would expect it to work. A minimal example for this is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{path}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\path!{#1}!}
\begin{document}
Testing the path command with: \code{this.texts.should.not.be.typeseted.on.a.single.line}.

Testing the path command with: \path!this.texts.should.not.be.typeseted.on.a.single.line!.
\end{document}
```

What is the error I am making when defining the new command?

Comment: Very interesting that the `\path` chooses to use `!` marks instead of curly braces. Looks like it causes problems. I couldn't check with `de-macro` how it expands.

Comment: @progo: The delimiter may be chosen arbitrarly. You could also use `+` or any other symbol not conained in the string.

Comment: yah, but why not use the regular `\command{args}` syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a brief look, `\path` does `\catcode` trickery, much like `\verb` does, and so, like `\verb`, it will not work correctly within other commands. (Cf. [Why doesn’t verbatim work within …?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin)) Obviously, you are doing something extra in your application, otherwise you could just say `\newcommand\code{\path}` or even `\let\code\path`, which works because the command will then let `\path` pick up the parameter and not do it itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figure that your link solves my question that I can not use `\path` inside the arguments of another comman.